# Relationship between tables (1:1, 1:M) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I'm creating a database and I have two tables:

Activity:

- activityId (PK)
- description

Request:

- requestID (PK)
- accepted

I'm a little bit confused because an Activity could have many Requests (1:m), but a Request can only have one Activity (1:1) and I don't know how would I implement this. Should I add a foreign key column in Request that references the id from Activity (1:m) or should I add an unique foreign key column in Activity that references the id from Request (1:1)? I would really like to understand this. Thanks!

Comment: Add  `Request.activityId` referencing `Activity.activityId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a table that has many references, you cannot add the references inside that table because you cannot know how many field must be added. So, just add the `Activity` id in that referenced table. In your example when an `Activity` has many `Request`s you cannot add MANY columns inside `Activity` table. So, for each request just add id of the `Activity` to refer to it. So in your example add a foreign key in `Request` table to refer to the `Activity` id:

Activity:

- Id (PK)
- description

Request:

- ID (PK)
- accepted
- activityID (FK)